# Angularfire2 Ionic2 firebase is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm having a problem trying to get the token from the current user.
It says that firebase is not defined, but I tried also with AngularFireAuth, etc.

And if I use the firebase object that I declare in the constructor, I can't access the auth() method that contains the current user.

This is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthProviders, AuthMethods, AngularFire, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2';

import { MainPage } from '../main/main';

/*
  Generated class for the Login page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public af: AngularFire, public aa: AngularFireAuth) { }

  // ionViewDidLoad() {
  //   console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  // }

  btnLogIn() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      email: 'aaa@bbb.com',
      password: '123456'
    }, {
        provider: AuthProviders.Password,
        method: AuthMethods.Password
      }).then((response) => {
        this.getUser();
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  getUser() {
    console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken());
  }


}
```

The error is at the bottom, in the method called getUser().

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

that should be `af.getAuth()` to get the current user I believe

[Api Doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/4630a8623deb253b5ea21270a3fa1093e4cc6ded/docs/api-reference.md)